# Python3 Code works in Jupyter and iPython, but fails when I run it as a script from command line

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I wrote some code in Jupyter, it works perfectly as I intend it to. Then, I used notepad, copy pasted the code to notepad, and run it as a script from cmd. However, the code seems to be bugged when I run from the cmd. I call function_1(), on both Jupyter and from cmd, and they give different results. I checked my code on iPython, and it works as intended on iPython, so the problem must be when I copy-paste it as a script.

```
def main():
    import sys
    with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as f:
        graph, from_where, to_where = read_graph(f)
    path = search_path(graph, from_where, to_where)
    print(path)
if __name__ == '__main__':
main()
```

These are the execute(? I'm a math student, I don't know the proper terminologies) code. I can upload everything (actual script, text file, jupyter ipynb) should it be needed.

Comment: Your indentation is wrong. The last line calling main() should be indented. Also, share the output when you run your scripts in jupyter, cmd and iPython, and explain how the results are different from what you expect.

Comment: @R.dV yes, I made an indentation mistake here, but on the script it is fine. I will edit my post